# How can I restore my Rails 4 binstubs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I regenerated my binstubs at some point. It used to be that `Spring` worked flawlessly and after the first time I brought up a Rails console, the console would come up instantly.

Now it appears that Spring is no longer running.

When I type:

```
rails console
```

I get:

```
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.3)
[1] pry(main)>
```

If I type:

```
spring rails console
```

I get the same message, but instead of the console coming up I just get returned to the command line.

How can I get this command working the way it does in a new Rails app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't want to delete my whole `bin` directory, and it was already added to `git`. So I just ran:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

and the messages went away.

Answer (score 4):

with rails 6: `rails app:update:bin`

Answer (score 3):

`bundle install --binstubs` per 
https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-install.1.html

Note that "the --binstubs option is sticky, meaning Bundler will keep adding binstubs for new gems in the future when you run just bundle install". That config is stored under .bundle/config.  Per https://coderwall.com/p/vhfxia/generate-only-the-binstubs-that-your-project-needs, it's recommended to `bundle binstubs [gem_name]` to install only the desired gem's binstubs instead.